# Blank output OpenMP program compiling with g++ on Windows

Tags: c++, openmp

I am compiling a OpenMP program using MinGW g++ (x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0) but get blank output.

My code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    printf("FIN\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```bash
g++ a.cpp -fopenmp
```

There is no error message. However, I run `a.exe` and get empty output.

Any idea?

Comment: If you remove the pragma do you suddenly get output?

Comment: Yes, I get noemal output without pragma statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's turned out that something went wrong with libstdc++-6.dll.

Just copy this file to the directory where .exe exists. Then OpenMP is back to normal.